# Which article should be used in this example?

Tags: articles

Which article should be used in this example?

Comment: I feel like you have failed to include the example.

Comment: Either one would work based on context. But that broader question should probably be asked on our sister site, [ELL.SE].

Comment: If this is the kind of question people ask on English Language Learners site, then great for them - they know more than the native speakers do (when compared to the questions posted here).

Comment: Your question is little removed from "Which is correct, 'a dog' or 'the dog'?" Please don't go on to insult people pointing this out.

Comment: Search this site for "which article". There are many answers to questions about whether to use "a" or "the".

Comment: To Ashworth: this site should not tolerate rude behavior. If you have anger to vent, please do it elsewhere.

For anyone else who may want to chime in, the adjective "prime" means "most important" or "of the highest quality or value" (Merriam). Does this not call for "the" instead of "a"?

What makes the use of "the prime" proper in 

"financial measures are no longer seen as the prime indicator of success"  

and the use of "a prime" the more accurate one in

"Homeownership is a prime indicator of success in an immigrant's housing trajectory"?

Comment: @MDX Edwin Ashworth is hardly being rude. There can be any number of *prime* things, just as there can be of *most important* things or *highest quality* things, and it is your misconception that there can be only one. *Mauritius and and Seychelles are prime locales for offshore banking*. *His wife and his children are his most important influences.* *To crush your enemies, to see them driven before you, and to hear the lamentations of their women are what is best in life*. *The* is suitable if you want to assert that there is only one, but being superlative and being singular are different.

Comment: @choster Superlative and singular are different, but superlative implies singular. Of course there can be any number of things that share the trait of being the most important things, but then you would say "this is one of the most important things", not "this is a most important thing", unless you mean "a very important thing".

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct. Your choice rests upon the context in which you are using the clause.

> *the* prime indicator of success

This implies that there *is only one* prime indicator of success.

> *a* prime indicator of success

This implies that there *could be more than one* indicator of success that could be considered prime.

Answer (score 0):

**Either is acceptable given your usage.**

Consider the text used to define these words:

> **the** (article).  A definite grammatical article.
>
> **a** (article).  The indefinite grammatical article.

When you say "a specific blah" or "a prime blah," you are using the article in a *definite* manner, thus `the` and `a prime` are synonymous.

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue that there is only one *prime* indicator, and I would therefore use the definite article. This is not borne out by common usage, however. You just need to decide if "prime indicator" is unique or if it can be plural. If plural, the indefinite "a" is grammatically correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, correct.

> Consider -
>
> > **The** prime indicator of success = **this/that** prime indicator of success.
> >
> > **A** prime indicator of success   = **some/any** prime indicator of success.